# Can't Enable Module through the Web Setup Wizard

Tags: admin, admin-panel, magento2.3.0, web-setup-wizard

I'm having some problems with my Magento2 setup.

I've installed a several extensions/modules that are having trouble actually installing and becoming part of our system.

I normally install with composer, do a `setup:upgrade` and `static:code:deploy` using cli.

While the module shows enabled in `app/etc/config.php` and in magento `module:status`, when I go to the Web Setup Wizard it's not enabled.

Furthermore, when I click on "Enable" in the Web Setup Wizard, the module name is replaced with "Null" and the readiness check fails almost completely.

[image: Enabling Module Error]

Any thoughts? What am I doing wrong here?

Steps to recreate.

1. Open Magento2.3
2. Select the "Web Setup Wizard" by going to System >
   Web Setup Wizard
3. Select the Module Manager
4. Find some Module that isn't enabled
5. Click Enable
6. Start Readiness Check

Answer (score 0):

Pls check if the cron is installed and working properly

This line may give you a clue

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/comp-mgr/trouble/cman/cron.html

Comment: Thanks. I'll give this a shot and respond back with the result

Answer (score 0):

This means your crons aren't setup. I set tasks for cron:run, setup:cron:run and for magentoroot/upgrade/cron.php. Once I created a schedule for those three, I had no more issues with the Web Setup Wizard.